# Handling Cumulocity Password Resets with a Custom UI

Tags: cumulocity

We have created a Cumulocity solution and created a very clean, simple interface for our users. We also offer a 'Change Password' feature to the solution users.

Changing the password in Cumulocity causes an email to be sent to the user containing a link for the user to follow and enter a new password. The issue is that the link always navigates the user to the built-in Cumulocity UI - this breaks the consistency of the user experience!

Is there a way we can create this password reset capability but have the email link direct the users to a customised UI to enter their new password?

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

- The content of the password reset email can be configured on system level. Mention just the host there, not a particular app ({host}?token={token}).
- Set your custom app to be the default app for the tenant. That will make sure that the user gets to your app when they click on the link.

Note: If you change the default app for a tenant, you may need to clean your browser cache to actually see the new default app.